# Disable Screen in iOS app?

Tags: swift, uiswitch, screens

I wanted to know if it is possible to disable a specific screen from appearing if the user slides a switch in a settings menu?

Comment: what do you mean by screen? A specific view controller or a view? If you are trying to solve this using Storyboards only, this is not possible. You can do it in code. You should have a look at NSUserDefaults.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about the actual iPhone screen and another app/lockscreen then no, but if it's a view controller screen then you could disable the buttons or any method that leads to it